# How do I fire a Giftapult?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So I saw that [Giftapults](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Giftapult) can be crafted cheaply, and I thought I'd use this as a nice way to get rid of some items I'm never going to use that might be valuable to others (no, not crates). I crafted a Giftapult and used it on another item to make a Loaded Giftapult.

Now I don't see how to use it.

- Clicking on it in my backpack in TF2 gives me a menu which allows me to rename or delete it.
- Some signs point to it being an Action Item, but when I try to equip it in the Action slot it's not in the valid items list, and in the all-items view it says "( Item cannot be used by this class. )". I tried all nine classes; same result.

I've tried all this while both connected to a server and not.

The Loaded Giftapult is marked "( Not Tradable )" but that seems to be normal.

Comment: Sadly, this has been bugged since one of the recent updates.  The backpack menu should have an option to launch it, but doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed in the [TF2 update for 1/27/15:](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/January_27,_2015_Patch)

> - Fixed wrapped Giftapult packages not having the "Deliver Gift" option in the context menu

To use a Giftapult, open up your backpack, scroll to the Giftapult desired, right click and it will open a context menu for launching it.